# Asp.net MVC action link

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, controller, actionlink

I am writing my first MVC app. While creating link for opening details view, I have to pass id.

In Controller method like as below:

```cs
public ActionResult getDetails(int UserMasetrId) 
{
    ...Some Code 
}
```

In VIEW link was generated as below:

```
<a title="View Details" href="@Url.Action("getDetails", "UserMaster", new {id=item.UserMasterId})"></a>
```

For above code link is generating as `...controllername/getDetails/13616`. But it throws error:

> "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter
> 'UserMasterId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method
> 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult getDetails(Int32)' in
> 'APP.Controllers.UserMasterController'. An optional parameter must be
> a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional
> parameter."

Now if I change action link as below?

```
<a title="View Details" href="@Url.Action("getDetails", "UserMaster", new {UserMasterId=item.UserMasterId})"></a>
```

It works fine but link change to  `...controllername/getDetails?UserMasterId=13616`

So please suggest any solution for parameter name as I write in action method and i want format of url not to show parameter name means the format of url should `conrtoller/actionmethod/parametervalue`.

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: Thank you very much.. it will help me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from all suggestions and after implementing these suggestions i came to decision that in link and in action method parameter name if you use same parameter name as suggested in default router, the URL will generate as 
`ControllerName/actionMthod/value` 
 and in all other case it will generate 
`ControllerName/actionMthod?ParamerName=value.`

Answer (score 0):

The parameter name in your function should match the query parameter in your button link.

```
<a title="View Details" href="@Url.Action("getDetails", "UserMaster", new { UserMasterId = item.UserMasterId})"></a>
```

You should also declare a Route if you're not using the default `Id` parameter.

```
[Route("ControllerName/getDetails/{UserMasterId}")]
public ActionResult getDetails(int? UserMasterId) 
{
   if (id == null)
   {
      return NotFound();
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, details is displayed. But the problem is that url format is changed to ControllerName/actionMthod?ParamerName=value instead of ControllerName/actionMthod/value.

Comment: @NileshkumarMPrajapati did you add the routing? Check the attribute routing in my code.

Comment: Is there like that if we set parameter name in action method is different than the name of default route parameter then the format of url like ControllerName/actionMthod?ParamerName=value. and if name specified for actionmethod parameter and default route parameter thant format will be ControllerName/actionMthod/value??

Answer (score 0):

What you are using is not `ActionLink`. You are generating a link for you `href` action only. You can generate a proper `a` tag using the HtmlHelper: `Html.ActionLink` like this:

```
Html.ActionLink("", "getDetails", "UserMaster", new { item.UserMasterId }, null)
```

This will generate anchor tag like this assuming `item.UserMasterId` is 1:

```
<a href="/UserMaster/getDetails/1"></a>
```

And change your `Controller` method to:

```
public ActionResult getDetails(int? id) 
{
    ...Some Code 
}
```

Comment: The problem is url format is changed to  ontrollerName/actionMthod?ParamerName=value instead of ControllerName/actionMthod/value.

Comment: @NileshkumarMPrajapati Did you try using the above Html Helper? I am using `Html.ActionLink` and not `Url.Action`

Comment: i did the same thing, but no solve the problem, but i came to conclusion which i mentioned as answer for this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you just started to learn MVC, it is better for you to learn it right way. You should use Route parameters, not QueryString parameters. So leave your link as it is

```
<a title="View Details" href="@Url.Action("getDetails", "UserMaster", new {id=item.UserMasterId})"></a>
```

but fix the action, your action is not an MVC style, should be

```
[Route("{userMasterId?}")]
public ActionResult getDetails(int? userMasterId) 
{
    ...Some Code 
}
```

but name  doesnt matter, important that route parameter and action parameter  names should be the same, you can use this as well

```
[Route("{id?}")]
public ActionResult getDetails(int? id) 
{
    ...Some Code 
}
```